# Enforce SQL Server to drop a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-drop

When I'm using `Management Studio Express` to drop a database there is an checkbox `"Close existing connections."` which close open database and enforce it to drop.

How can i drop a database programmatic by closing open connections and check it's ever exists before?

Comment: While on that drop screen, if you click on the icon to generate a script, you'll see how it's done in the back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the "script" icon on the drop screen, as suggested in the comments by Randolph Potter (this assumes that your database name is "test"):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'test'
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [test]    Script Date: 06/30/2010 09:12:29 ******/
DROP DATABASE [test]
GO
```